# Examples of evolving networks in linguistics

Tags: questions

I'm a master student working on networks analysis in general. A network is something that has nodes and there are links between the nodes. Nodes and links could have attributes. An evolving network is one that changes overtime (new nodes and links are added..etc). An example of that is Facebook. Nodes are users and links represent the friendship relationship. Users have attributes (gender, age ..etc). A Facebook network as you know is an example of a social network.

The issue is that so many people studied traditional evolving networks like social networks, the web, or transportation networks. Currently I'm looking for novel examples of evolving networks to study them. So I thought there might be some examples in *linguistics* that could represent some kind of an evolving network.

So my question: Can you give me examples in *linguistics* for evolving networks? I dunno maybe words as nodes and links as some kind of a relationship, but the network evolves somehow.

Answer (score 1):

There is an approach to the syntax of natural language that can be consistent with the type of networks that the question is asking about. In a dependency grammar (DG) (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_grammar), words are nodes that are linked into a structure by dependencies. Syntactic structure in dependency grammars might be represented in the following way (the tree is taken from the article *Grammatical relation* in Wikipedia):

::[image]

The edges connecting the words in the tree are dependencies, and each of these dependencies bears a syntactic function that indicates how the entire subtree functions with repsect to the entirety.

Most work in DG assumes tree structures like the one just shown. One prominent dependency grammar, however, assumes networks as opposed to trees. This DG is called *Word Grammar* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_grammar); it is the grammar framework developed by Richard Hudson. The difference between trees and networks is that in a network, a given word can have two or more heads, as opposed to just one head. The book you probably want to take a look at is this one:

::Language Networks: The New Word Grammar, Richard Hudson, 2007

You will find there a sophisticated system of syntax and grammar that may include the type of networks that you are looking for in natural language.

Comment: Yes, Hudson's work is very good. Whether it's suited to the purposes of anyone reading it is a different matter. But it's quite comprehensive and sensible.

Comment: 1- the image doesn't appear. 2-is this an *evolving* network?!

Comment: Hopefully the image will be corrected soon. I have asked for help in including images in answers at the related meta site. The tree I want to include is at the bottom of the following article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_function. Concerning "evolving networks" vs. "non-evolving" ones, I do not know, but part of your question calls up a clear association with Word Grammar. You wrote "...words as nodes and links...". Anyone who reads that and has some exposure to Word Grammar and its emphasis on networks cannot help but think of Word Grammar.

Answer (score 1):

Your wish is my command:

Hills, T. T., Maouene, M., Maouene, J., Sheya, A. & Smith, L. B. (2009) Categorical Structure among shared features in networks of early-learned nouns. Cognition, 112(3), 381-396.

Hills, T., Maouene, M., Maouene, J. & Sheya, A., Smith L.B (2009) "Longitudinal Analysis of Early Semantic Networks: Preferential Attachment or Preferential Acquisition?" Psychological Science, 20(6), 729-739.

Steyvers, M., & Tenenbaum, J. B. (2005). The large-scale structure of semantic networks: statistical analyses and a model of semantic growth. Cognitive Science, 29(1), 41–78. doi:10.1207/s15516709cog2901_3

Vitevitch, M. S., & Goldstein, R. (2014). Keywords in the mental lexicon. Journal of Memory and Language, 73, 131–147. doi:10.1016/j.jml.2014.03.005

Comment: are these *evolving* networks? can I construct a dataset (network recorded over time) out of them so I can study the data?

Comment: The Hills psych science paper and the S&T paper both posit network growth mechanisms. I'm not sure about the Hills cognition or Vitevitch papers.